# python/miniconda - proper use of environment variable paths

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, conda, miniconda

**TLDR:** How should miniconda environments be added to the environment variables such that multiple conda environments will run with minimal fuss?

*Long Story/Background*

I'm on Windows 10 and got fed up with trying to use python directly and decided to give miniconda a go. I'm running python 3.8 with the main installed package being numpy. Everything was fine in the console, but Pycharm had the classic `Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.` After trying reinstallation, I found another question that had gotten it to work by adding more folders to the system path. This worked only when the additional library paths

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.conda\envs\num38
C:\Users\USERNAME\.conda\envs\num38\DLLs
C:\Users\USERNAME\.conda\envs\num38\Lib
C:\Users\USERNAME\.conda\envs\num38\Library
C:\Users\USERNAME\.conda\envs\num38\Library\bin
C:\Users\USERNAME\.conda\envs\num38\Scripts
```

were directly added to the system path, not as a secondary path variable, i.e. `%num38_path%`. I also tried it with the secondary path as a runtime environment variable for the configuration in Pycharm but that also didn't work.

Why doesn't this secondary path method work?

I'm currently only using this one virtual environment, but if, in the future, I want to have another conda environment, would these paths being in system path be an issue?

Comment: _"Pycharm had the classic Importing the numpy c-extensions failed."_ Never had it!

Comment: Please upgrade your problem description to a [mre]. Otherwise, it's impossible to answer. Pycharm supposedly supports Miniconda, so if the latter requires some extra PATH entries, it should be automatically adding them when you run stuff from within Pycharm.